# how we can use usesCleartextTraffic in react instead of react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, ssl

i have MERN stack App in which the front end code and backend code hosted on Aws but the back end is 3.34 Ip something like this but the ip show's us unsecure http. when i live my front end code and put back end ip it will not work in production level.
i use strict-ssl false but it does not work.